# Sorting by author last name

Tags: bibtex

I am using document class `article`, and using the following to refer to references:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{MyRef}
```

An example of the article entry is like this:

```
@ARTICLE{KG:2001,
     author = "{Ratnesh Kumar and Vijay K. Garg}",
     title = "{some Title}",
     journal = "{IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control}",
     year = {2001},
     volume = {46},
     number = {4},
     month = "",
     pages = {593--606},
     publisher = "",
     address = "" 
}
```

An example of the techreport entry is like this:

```
@TECHREPORT{E:N:T:Z:2003,
        author  = "{Sameh Elnikety and Erich Nahum and John Tracey and Willy Zwaenepoel}",
        title   = "{Some Title}",
        type ="",
        institution = "",
        year  = "2003",
        month = "", 
        number = ""
 
}
```

An example of the in proceedings entry is like this:

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{H:G:2001,
        author = "Kau Hun and Diana Glanen",
        title = "{Some title}",
        booktitle = "{Proceedings of the First International Workshop}",
        series = "Lecture Notes in Computer Science",
        volume = "1",
        pages = "304--305",
        year = "2001",
        month="",
        location="",
        editor = "",
        publisher = "Springer-Verlag",
        address = "London, UK" 
}
```

The file name that contains the entries is `MyRef.bib`

For some reason, the references are ordered by first name and not last. As I have many bib entries, could you tell me what is the fastest way I could fix this?

Comment: Try  `biblatex`. Its default style is `numeric` which is about the same as `plain` style. Besides it's easier to customise than `bst` files.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With just one bib entry it's impossible to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks for the suggestion. How can I change my current file to biblatex? Is this option available in TeXNic Center?

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. I added more examples. I tend to copy one entry and then change its contents, so they should be the same in each category.

Comment: Either `author="<names>"` or `author={<names>}`; the braces around the author names are the problem.

Comment: In BibTeX you should specify author names as _Surname1, Given Name1 and Surname2, Given Name2, ....._

Comment: @MarcvanDongen That is only required for complex names: simple `John Smith` examples work fine without it.

Comment: @JosephWright I suppose the definition of _complex_ is _where it doesn't work without it?_

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Broadly :-) Multi-part first/surnames are the obvious case. I was only trying to get at the fact that `John Smith` is perfectly valid input for BibTeX: the porblem in this question is not how the names are formatted in that sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to format your bibliography file correctly.  Writing

```
author = "{xxx yyy and aaa bbb}"
```

will be interpreted as a one single author whose name is simply a surname.  You should write

```
author = {xxx yyy and aaa bbb}
```

or better

```
author = {yyy, xxx and bbb, aaa}
```

with each name as Last, First:

[image: Sample output]

```
@TechReport{E:N:T:Z:2003,
  author =   {Elnikety, Sameh and Nahum, Erich and Tracey, John
                  and Zwaenepoel, Willy},
  title =    {Some Title},
  institution =  {Some Inst.},
  year =     2003
}

@InProceedings{H:G:2001,
  author =   {Hun, Kau and Glanen, Diana},
  title =    {Some title},
  booktitle =    {Proceedings of the First International Workshop},
  series =   {Lecture Notes in Computer Science},
  volume =   1,
  pages =    {304--305},
  year =     2001,
  publisher =    {Springer-Verlag},
  address =  {London, UK}
}

@Article{KG:2001,
  author =   {Kumar Ratnesh and Garg, Vijay K.},
  title =    {Some Title},
  journal =  {IEEE Transactions on Automatic Control},
  year =     2001,
  volume =   46,
  number =   4,
  pages =    {593--606}
}
```

created with the latex file

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{MyRef}
\end{document}
```

A very good explanation of the syntax of `bib` files may be found in Part 3 of [Tame the BeaST](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast).  As Jospeh Wright points out you can use `"..."` instead of `{...}` but using both as `"{...}"` will double quote the contents and lead to the unwanted interpretation of your input.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to make sure your input follows the format. I found google scholar always can give a good format. So I always copy and paste the bibtex entry from google scholar to my *.bib file.

Second, you need to pick up a certain package to read *.bib and work with latex. I used "biblatex". As far as biblatex speaking, you can control the output format when you include this package in the main file. Say:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,backref,style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,firstinits=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}
```

The "style" control how it looks like in the context: here I chose authoryear; and the "sorting" control how literatures are sorted in the final bibliography part: here I chose nyt, which stands for "author name - year - date".

There is more useful information available at:

https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX#!#Reference_guide